# Цепные синонимы

Tags: дефект, синонимы-меток

Хотел синонимизировать [refactoring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring) и [рефакторинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3), но он не даётся с сообщением

> Не удалось предложить синоним:
>  
> Синоним refactoring для рефакторинг уже существует, цепочки запрещены

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Подозреваю, что это связано с тем, что [рефакторинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) предложен (но НЕ утверждён) как синоним другой метки. Сам [рефакторинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) на странице синонимов найти не удалось.

[image: скриншот синонимов]

Считаю, что описание ошибки неверное и вообще не отражает смысл происходящего.

Comment: Добавил квадратных скобочек вокруг меток заодно.

Comment: Кажется, [модератор сломался](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eURB7.jpg).

Comment: Ну и тут нет проблем локализации как таковых, оригинальная строка «A synonym from $source$ to $target$ exists, chains are not allowed».

Comment: @alexolut, но ведь утверждение неверное...

Comment: Исходное или переведённое?

Comment: @alexolut, оба?)

Comment: Если исходная формулировка семантически неверна, то это проблемы движка, а не локализации. Нельзя переводить "black" как "белое", сначала оно должно стать "white".

Comment: @Qwertiy А может ли это быть как-то связано с этим вопросом https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6583/220571 Ну то есть что-то не объединили, а только синонимизировали?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, там уже было объединено и синонимизировано. Я переставил синоним и объединил снова с пустой меткой, поставив галочку создать синоним. По идее, должно быть верно. Тьфу.. Не то отвечаю. Это про минт был ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy Про минт подождём до завтра, а здесь баг ещё с прошлого года, хорошо бы его исследовать.