# В каком случае надо объединять метки, а в каком достаточно синонимизации?

Tags: поддержка, faq, метки, синонимы-меток, замена-меток

Чем отличаются синонимизация и объединение меток?
В каком случае надо использовать объединение, а в каком достаточно синонимизации?

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: У меня лежит статья для [перевода](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/), которая объясняет эти механизмы, но она пока еще не готова (совсем).

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7311/15479

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Синонимизировать метки или объединять? Объединять и синонимизировать! Но это не точно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7306/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9d%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Answer (score 4):

Немало полезной информации можно найти в статье [«Tag Folksonomy and Tag Synonyms»](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) блога Stack Overflow.

### Что такое синонимы меток?

Синоним метки – это, как правило, другая метка, имеющая то же самое значение, например, [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) и [алгоритмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b). Порой метка, являющаяся подмножеством другой метки, также считается синонимом, к примеру, [java-se](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-se) и [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Система организует метки в мастер-синоним связки.  Все попытки использовать синонимичную для любой основной метку приведёт к автоматической конвертации оной к основной. Таким образом, пользователи могут вводить метку-синоним при написании вопроса, но отображаться будет основная метка. Редактирование вопроса, помеченного меткой-синонимом, преобразует её в основную метку. Аналогичным образом, когда пользователи ищут вопросы, помеченные синонимом, будет отображаться список вопросов, использующих основную метку.

Тем не менее, существующие вопросы с метками-синонимами, созданные до синонимизации, которые после процесса синонимизации не редактировались, продолжат использовать метку-синоним.

Полный список синонимов доступен на  [`/tags/synonyms`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms).

### Как метки-синонимы можно отличить от "реальных" меток?

Метки-синонимы заменяются соответствующей основной, например, когда вы производите поиск по метке, пытаетесь назначить метку вопросу, переходите по ссылке на метку.

Обратите внимание, что у пользователя редко бывает необходимость различать типы меток.

### Как создаются новые синонимы? Кто может создавать синонимы?

- Пользователи с репутации более 2500 (1250 на бета сайтах) и общими рейтингом ответов 5 и более по метке могут предлагать синонимы по ней.
- Пользователи с чистым рейтингом по ответам (голоса «за» минус голоса «против») от 5 могут голосовать за синонимы.

Предложения будут автоматически приняты как только наберут 4 голоса, или будут автоматически удалено при достижении рейтинга `-1`.
Также, модераторы могут создавать синонимы без необходимости проведения стадии голосования.

Если не хватает людей для принятия синонима, или вы не уверены, что создание синонима – хорошая идея, начните обсуждение на [мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com) с метками `обсуждение`, `метки`, `синонимы-меток`.

Панель модератора по работе с синонимами доступна по пути `/tags/TAG_NAME/synonyms`, например, `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/synonyms`.

Опять же, когда синоним создан, синонимичная метка не будет заменена в текущих вопросах, но больше не может быть использована в новых вопросах (основная метка будет использована взамен). Это позволяет без проблем откатиться в случае ошибки.

### Как удалить/откатить/отменить плохую метку?

Только модераторы могут поправить "плохие" синонимы. Таким образом, единственное, что нужно сделать, — это задать вопрос на мете с объяснением проблемы по синониму. Используйте метки, описанные выше. Дайте сообществу несколько дней, чтобы увидеть возможные альтернативные предложения. Как только дискуссия будет завершена, модератор применит соответствующие изменения. Если нет ответа модератора в течение нескольких дней после консенсуса сообщества, свяжитесь с модератором в чате.

### Что такое объединение меток?

Все "хорошие" синонимы в идеале должны быть **объединены** ([источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262288/255554)). Это проверит все текущие вопросы, помеченные меткой, чего не происходит автоматически при создании синонима. Поскольку объединение не (беспроблемно) обратимо, осуществлять объединение меток нужно с осторожностью. Только модераторы могут выполнять объединение меток.

Объединение, само по себе, не создаёт синонимов, что оставляет возможность пересоздания объединённой метки пользователем позже. В большинстве случаев вы захотите создать синоним (или убедиться, что синоним существует), чтобы будущие попытки использовать объединённую метку заменяли её основной. Тем не менее, объединение без синонимизации иногда полезно, например, при переименовании метки.

Более подробную информацию можно найти в [этой секции для модераторов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119377).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [«What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/26019)</sub>

Comment: Коллеги, предлагаю сделать объединение " math"( старый вариант математики) и "математика" и в итоге убрать вообще из оборота старую метку. Останется одна -математика. А старые метки автоматически переименуете.

Comment: @Volk модераторы не отслеживают комментарии к старым вопросам. Лучше обратитесь к  
αλεχολυτ в вашем новом вопросе.