# Странно объединились метки про консоль

Tags: дефект, метки, синонимы-меток

Сейчас метка [консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c) имеет три [синонима](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C/synonyms):

- [console](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console)
- [terminal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal)
- [терминал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb)

Судя по всему на момент синонимизации метка [console](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console) уже имела краткое описание. И теперь возникают довольно странные ситуации, например, на [странице меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?page=7&tab=popular) можно увидеть такой текст:

> [image: console]

А если навести курсор, то всплывающее окно уже содержит описание из главной метки:

> [image: консоль]

При этом остаётся возможность редактирования описания метки [console](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console) через ссылку "править" (см.первую картинку).

Comment: Они не объединились похоже. Синоним создался, а на объединение не нажали, поэтому console еще осталась в вопросах.А вот поведение со всплывающими подсказками действительно странное.

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что их синонимизировали, но не объединили. [В каком случае надо объединять метки, а в каком достаточно синонимизации?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6583/15479)

Я список даже таких кривых меток составлял: [Поправить синонимизированные метки, которые не были объединены](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7313/15479).