# Объединение меток о векторах

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие вот метки:

- [vector](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vector) (535 вопросов)
- [вектор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80) (165 вопросов)
- [векторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) (27 вопросов)

Надо их объединить.

Comment: Чем отличается синонимизация от объединения?

Comment: Это синонимы ;-)

Comment: Аааа, понял :-)

Comment: @PeterKolosov при объединении теряется история меток

Comment: Может быть, английский термин используется для класса C++, а часть русских - относится к векторам из геометрии?

Comment: @MBo на enSO есть [stdvector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdvector), у нас отдельной нет. Но std::vector это всё равно вектор.

Comment: Я к тому, что вряд ли вопросы типа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422529/, попавшие теперь под `vector`, имеют отношение к  `Вектор представляет собой одномерный массив...` Как разруливать - не знаю. При введении специальной длинной метки - она просто не будет использоваться.

Comment: В метке действительно собраны разные вопросы: про std::vector, про векторную алгебру, про классы типа Vector2 в C# и т.д. На необходимость синонима это в данном случае не влияет, но на будущее, нужно в теме писать минимальное обоснование, что метки действительно синонимы, и имеют определенное значение.

Comment: @MBo описание метки - машинный перевод описания с английского сайта, так что не ищите там глубокий смысл...

Answer (score -2):

Синонимизировал к vector (как имеющей описание). Объединять пока не стал.

О том, чем отличается синонимизация от объединения можно почитать здесь: [В каком случае надо объединять метки, а в каком достаточно синонимизации?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6583/176217)

Comment: Объедини, раз начал, смысл оставлять.

Comment: @aepot а зачем?

Comment: Чтобы используя одну а не 3 метки можно было получить все релевантные вопросы. Фильтрация, поиск, отслеживание удобнее.

Comment: @aepot оно по идее должно обновиться, ибо иначе на старые метки вообще не выйти было бы. Надо подождать, имхо. Обновилось уже.

Comment: Именно так, на старые метки и вопросы по ним не выйти без объединения.

Comment: @aepot нажми метку [tag:vector] и выбери последнюю страницу. Там кеширование что ли. Или бага.

Comment: Просто вопросы, помеченные их авторами несколькими метками сразу. Ты синонимы звавел, а метки в вопросах существующих не переписал (объединение). Поэтому оно выглядит ровно так, как было до введения синонимов. Хотя, может баг какой-то.

Comment: @aepot пусть выглядит. Не вижу в этом проблемы. При новой правке - синонимы уйдут. Зато сейчас видна история.

Comment: Делай, как считаешь нужным, я доверяю тебе.